# Can I create two pods for elastic search under same namespace in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, deployment

I have requirement for two different version of elastic search, can I deploy two different pods of elastic search under same namespace in kubernetes cluster?

Dockerfile for elasticserach:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.12.0
USER elasticsearch
EXPOSE 9200
```

Second Dockerfile:

```
FROM elasticsearch:7.5.1
USER elasticsearch
EXPOSE 9200
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

If you want to deploy a bare pod

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: "elastic search"
  labels:
    app: "eleastic-search"
spec:
  containers:
    - name: "eleastic-search"
      image:  elasticsearch:7.12.0
      ports:
        - name: es
          containerPort: 9200
          protocol: TCP
```

for the second one you can use a different version and you need to use a different name

you can also use a deployment.
which will deploy 3 replicas of elasticsearch:7.12.0

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: "elastic search"
  labels:
    app: "eleastic-search"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: "eleastic-search"
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: "eleastic-search"
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: "eleastic-search"
        image: elasticsearch:7.12.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
```

** make sure the metadata.name is not conflicting with each other.
both examples they will deployed in default namespace.
you can define namespace under the metadata section

I would recommend you to go through the offical docs of kubernetes
[pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/)
[deployments](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)
[services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)